# How can I modify my HTML file with node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

```js
require('dotenv').config()
var ComfyJS = require("comfy.js");

var firstplayer = document.getElementById("firstcharactername");

var maxPlayer = 0;
var totalAmount = 0;
var playerOne = "player1";
var playerTwo = "player2";
var playerOneScore = 0;
var playerTwoScore = 0;

var playerOneHealth = 50;
var playerTwoHealth = 50;
var playerOneTurnNumber = 1;
var playerTwoTurnNumber = 0;

function randomFunc(min, max)
{
 return Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
}

ComfyJS.onCommand = ( user, command, message, flags, extra ) => {
    function rpsPicker()
    {
        var randomnumberRPS = randomFunc(1,3);
        if(randomnumberRPS === 1)
        {
            ComfyJS.Say("@" + user + " Rock");
        }
        else if(randomnumberRPS === 2)
        {
            ComfyJS.Say("@" + user + " Paper");
        }
        else if(randomnumberRPS === 3)
        {
            ComfyJS.Say("@" + user + " Scissors");
        }
    }
    function headtailPicker()
    {
        var randomnumberHeadTail = randomFunc(1,2);
        if(randomnumberHeadTail === 1)
        {
            ComfyJS.Say("@" + user + " Heads");
        }
        else
        {
            ComfyJS.Say("@" + user + " Tail");
        }
    }    
///////////////////////////////////////////////COMMANDS/////////////////////////////////////////////////
    if( command === "roll1" && user === playerOne) 
    {   
        var randomNumber1 = randomFunc(2,11);
        ComfyJS.Say("@"+user + " You've rolled two dices equals to " + randomNumber1+".");
        playerOneScore += randomNumber1;
        ComfyJS.Say("@"+user + "'s total amount is "+ playerOneScore);
    }
    else if(command === "roll2" && user === playerTwo)
    {
        var randomNumber2 = randomFunc(2,11);
        ComfyJS.Say("@"+user + " You've rolled two dices equals to " + randomNumber2+".");
        playerTwoScore += randomNumber2;
        ComfyJS.Say("@"+user + "'s total amount is "+ playerTwoScore);
    }
    else if(command === "compare")
    {
        if(playerOneScore > playerTwoScore)
        {
            ComfyJS.Say(playerOne+" won.")
        }
        else
        {
            ComfyJS.Say(playerTwo+" won.")
        }
    }

    else if (command === "joingame")
    {
        maxPlayer += 1;
        if(maxPlayer === 1)
        {
            playerOne = user;
            ComfyJS.Say("@"+user + " has joined the game " + ".");
            firstplayer.innerText = user;
        }
        else if(maxPlayer === 2)
        {
            playerTwo = user;
            ComfyJS.Say("@"+user + " has joined the game " + ".");
        }
        else if(maxPlayer > 2)
        {
            ComfyJS.Say("Max player limit!")
        }
    }

    else if(command === "resetgame" && flags.broadcaster == true)
    {
        totalAmount = 0;
        maxPlayer = 0;
        playerOne = "player1";
        playerTwo = "player2";
        playerOneScore = 0;
        playerTwoScore = 0;
    }

    else if (command === "rps")
    {
        rpsPicker();
    }

    else if (command === "flipcoin")
    {
        headtailPicker();
    }
///////////////////////////////////////////////COMBAT GAME//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    else if( command === "attack1" && user === playerOne) 
    {   
        if (playerOneTurnNumber > 0)
        {
            var randomNumberAttack1 = randomFunc(5,12);
            ComfyJS.Say("/me " + "@"+user + " hits "+ randomNumberAttack1 + " damage to his opponent.");
            playerTwoHealth -= randomNumberAttack1;
            ComfyJS.Say("/me " + "@"+playerTwo + "'s remaining health is " + playerTwoHealth);
            playerOneTurnNumber -= 1;
        }  
        else
        {
            ComfyJS.Say("/me It's not your turn.");
        }
    }

    else if( command === "attack2" && user === playerTwo) 
    {   
        if (playerTwoTurnNumber > 0)
        {
            var randomNumberAttack2 = randomFunc(5,12);
            ComfyJS.Say("/me " + "@"+user + " hits "+ randomNumberAttack2 + " damage to his opponent.");
            playerOneHealth -= randomNumberAttack2;
            ComfyJS.Say("/me " + "@"+playerOne + "'s remaining health is " + playerOneHealth);
            playerTwoTurnNumber -= 1;
        }
        else
        {
            ComfyJS.Say("/me It's not your turn.");
        }       
    }

    else if( command === "endturn1" && user === playerOne)
    {
        ComfyJS.Say("/me " + playerOne + " ends his turn.");
        playerTwoTurnNumber += 1;
    }

    else if( command === "endturn2" && user === playerTwo)
    {
        ComfyJS.Say("/me " + playerTwo + " ends his turn.");
        playerOneTurnNumber += 1;
    }

  }




///////////////////////////////////////////WELCOMER/////////////////////////////////////////////////
ComfyJS.onJoin = ( user, self, extra ) =>
{
    console.log(user);
    ComfyJS.Say("@"+user+" Welcome!");
}
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

ComfyJS.onChat = ( user, message, flags, self, extra ) =>
    {
        console.log( user, message, extra.userColor, flags.broadcaster);
    }



ComfyJS.Init( process.env.TWITCHUSER, process.env.OAUTH, "shiftyshifterr" );
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/comfy.js@latest/dist/comfy.min.js"></script>

    <h1>TEST GAME</h1>
    <div class="character-container">
        <div class="first-character-container">
            <p id="firstcharactername" class="first-character-name"></p>
            <img src="firstplayer.gif" alt="firstplayer">
        </div>
        <div>
            <img src="secondplayer.gif" alt="secondplayer">
            <p id="secondcharactername" class="second-character-name"></p>
        </div>    
    </div>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm using node.js to build a twitch bot.

But when I try to modify my HTML via that javascript file I get an error like:

`ReferenceError: the document is not defined`

I've searched for it and found out that node.js is server sided so I can not use `document.getElementById` with it.

But I want to modify my HTML file by using that node.js javascript file.

Is there any way to do that and how?

**What i'my trying to do here is that when they type joingame command user name will be written in p tag in my HTML file.**

I'm pretty new to developing so sorry if I messed up with a question.

Comment: What HTML file? If you're writing a twitch bot then you'll likely be dealing with messages sent to and from a chatroom with no sign of HTML at all.

Comment: if you want to do it in your server, you will need to read the HTML file using the fs library and modify it like it was a string

Comment: It will be helpful if you can post here what you are trying and where you are facing the issue(code part)..

Comment: please provide a minimal reproducing example, so we can understand better what you do

Comment: I added a part of them i hope this will be useful

Comment: @Shifty — The relationship between the JavaScript and the HTML and Node and Twitch in that code is a complete mystery.

Comment: [Pictures of code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) are not very helpful.

Comment: @Quentin i guess i can provide my full code now. I know it's pretty beginner and bad lol but my problem is not related with js code. I just want to create graphics(on html) for my game that can be played in twitch chat and i can not reach DOM because it's node js

Answer (score 0):

As you have correctly identified, you cannot reach document from server-side, because that only exists in the browser. You will need to [parse](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-html-parser) the HTML if you want to work with it on Node JS, server-side.

You will need to install it like

```
npm install --save node-html-parser
```

and then you will be able to do something like

```
import { parse } from 'node-html-parser';
//Some code
var document = parse(yourhtml);
```

Comment: I see my answer has been downvoted. I think it is correct, but would be glad to see whether there are problems with it, so I could edit it if needed.

Comment: Even with parsing, the solution isn't right, I mean see it this way, What he is asking is completely not a thing, nodeJS is not for this, even if you use a View Engine, or parse an HTML that is one time editable and you can't do anything with nodeJS once it is renedered.

Comment: @AshutoshKumar I would like to inform you about a concept called server-side HTML parsing. One may need to parse HTML server-side for many possible reasons. Among those reasons you may find use-cases, like the creation of HTML templates that will be reusable later. A server may parse the HTML received as a response of an API call as well. You seem not to be aware of the fact that there are some perfectly valid situations when HTML needs to be parsed on server-side. My answer describes how that can be done, since the user is specifically interested about parsing HTML by NodeJS.

Comment: @AshutoshKumar of course, a pretty frequent situation is that the HTML is rendered into the browser where browser-side Javascript can be used in order to work along with the HTML. But the asker works on the server-side. He/she has an HTML there and cannot parse it, because the code which he/she found for that purpose was written for browsers. So, my answer is a solution for the question. One can work on the HTML in the browser as well, but that is not the situation here.

Comment: Oh, well thanks for the info, but I do know the concept of server-side HTML parsing and rendering on the browser, I just meant to say his question actually has no valid answer, if you see it, only the notion of that he needs to shift from browser side HTML to server-side parsing,,

Comment: @AshutoshKumar I understand your point of view. You can leave a comment at the question to let the asker know that you think that something else needs to be done in your opinion.

Comment: :), I think I understand it now, the answer must not be guidance to choose an option right?
I will keep that in my mind.
Till then Happy Coding :)

Comment: @AshutoshKumar the answer needs to address the question. That is, if there are multiple choices to solve an issue the asker is asking about, then you may describe those choices, but to critique the approach manifesting in the question you need to refer to the comment section. So, if you ask me how one can swim, then my answer needs to address your question about swimming. If, for some reason I think that using a ship would be better for you, that's fine, but that's a comment, not an answer. I oversimplified the example, because your comment may be a good one, but you probably understand it.

Comment: Awesome :) You simplified it for me...
I got you, I hope I will be more of a help in the future :)

Comment: Thanks. Happy asking, answering and commenting.

Answer (score -1):

`document.getElementById` interacts with your "HTML document" on runtime. If you need to edit your "HTML file" contents you need something like this:

```
var fs = require('fs');
 
fs.readFile('index.txt', 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;
 
    var newValue = 'new content';
 
    fs.writeFile('index.txt', newValue, 'utf-8', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('Done!');
    })
})
```

[Source](https://riptutorial.com/node-js/example/10102/changing-contents-of-a-text-file)

Comment: reveal yourself mysterious voter : j

Answer (score -1):

In this example -

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello World!'))

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening at http://localhost:${port}`))
```

https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html

if you notice the `res.send` - you are sending the html there

If you post your nodejs snippets, we can work further.

Comment: There's no suggestion in the question that they are using Express or writing an HTTP server at all. They said they were writing a Twitch bot.

Comment: Here is an example of a twitch bot written for a browser that works both via node ( see examples) and on the browser as standalone - https://github.com/twitch-js/twitch-js#browser-iife - Without additional code context, we are all working with the minimal direction provided in the original question.